# My for loop keeps going despite the condition met

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

n is equal to 2 when its loop is over, but by the last "if" statement it's somehow 3. )
can not figure out where it's changing.
because the last `if` condition isn't being met the for loop keeps going instead of returning `true` (`for(int i=0;i<Board[i].length;i++)`) and ) get an out of bounds exception.

so two questions -

1. can u spot where n changes?
2. how come the for loop with I keeps going despite the condition being met?
   `Board[i].length=3` and the loop just keeps going and gives me an out of bounds exception instead of exiting the for loop and returning me the false after it.

```
public boolean ColChecker() {
    int n=0;
    // create boolean array and set all values to false
    boolean[] isExist = new boolean[10];
    for(int i=0;i<isExist.length;i++) 
        isExist[i]=false;
        
    //loop over columns and test using whosThereCol method
    for(int i=0;i<Board[i].length;i++) {
        for(int col=0;col<Board[0][0].getLength();col++) {
            for(n=0;n<Board.length;n++) 
                Board[n][i].whosThereCol(col,isExist);
                    
            //if array still has missing values, column incomplete - return false
            for(int j=1;j<10;j++) 
                if(!isExist[j]) 
                    return false;
            //if no missing values, initialize array to false values for next iteration of for loop
            for(int j=1;j<10;j++) 
                isExist[j]=false;
                            
                    
        // "if" statement checks if this is the last column in the last square, if so, we passed all the tests. return true     
        if(i+1==Board[0].length&&col+1==Board[0][0].getLength()&&n+1==Board.length)
            return true;                
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `n++` at the end of the `for` statement will get executed after the last loop also.

Consider this code:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
System.out.println("=========");
System.out.println(i);
```

this will output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
=========
10
```

Comment: Wow, this really confuses me. not sure how to use for loops now, how do the other for loops stay in bounds? why does my "i" and "col" variables act as expected and stay 1 value below bound and n doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't need the condition at the end. Since you can also simply say when all 3 loops have run through: return true;
What I first notice as an error, you compare the top of your For loop with Board[i], but further down the comparison value is Board[0]. So your condition can't be true if not the length of Board[i] is always the same.
[image]

You also should change your For Loop Order maybe to this:

```
 for(n=0; n<Board.length; n++){
            for(int i=0;i<Board[n].length;i++) {
                for(int col=0;col<Board[n][i].getLength();col++) {
                    Board[n][i].whosThereCol(col,isExist);
                }
                //Your further Code
            }
        }
```

Comment: you are right about Board[i], thanks, ill change it. how do i say when all 3 loops have run through: return true ? also do you understand why n equals the for loop condition and the other variables stay< condition?

Comment: you can just change your final line from `return false;` to `return true;` I guess it will be very helpfull for you if you write all your loops with {} so its more clear their the loops starts and end.

Comment: i just removed the if and added the return true outside of the loops, makes sense as you say. but i still get an out of bounds exception. instead of ending for loop and returning true it just keeps going

Comment: thats because your loops are in the false order. You should put the n loop at the top and than iterate with the i loop `for(int i =0; i<Board[n].length; i++)` at the moment your stop condition dosnt make sense because i can be higher than 'Board[n].lenght'

Comment: changing the order will not perform the same action, it will not do what i want it to do with your code

Comment: in this case you have to check if Board[i] is valid because it can be not valid

Comment: how do i learn about this? im very new to programming